# YouTube API - Published Data is wrong?

Tags: .net, youtube, youtube-api

If you open [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ALLEjVi-cE&feature=player_embedded) video you can see the published data : 09/apr/2008

But If I get the video trought .NET API and I do :

```
video.Updated.Year.ToString()
```

it prints 2011. Why?

If you see the XML you can see

```
<published>2008-04-09T18:32:39.000Z</published>
<updated>2011-10-30T16:14:02.000Z</updated>
```

so what's the method I need to call on Video object to access to that  field?

### EDIT

I process the date with `video.Updated.Year.ToString()` on the feed after calling `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo/uploads/?start-index=260&max-results=50&orderby=published`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution : just use `video.YouTubeEntry.Published.Year`.

Thanks anyway!